# django abstract model to have slugfield

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, slug

I want all my models to have SlugField however it seems like its not a DRY principle for each and every model to have:

```
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
```

I want to implement this as follows:

**Base Model**

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

**Company Model**

```
class Company(BaseModel):

    code = models.CharField(max_length=2, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Companies'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My other models will inherit BaseModel to have those fields inherited however, whenever I save new record, SlugField is empty. Anyone could enlighten me on this please!

Comment: You need to populate `SlugField` yourself based on the target field, in your case maybe `name` field

Comment: @Lemayzeur is right. In addition to that; it is probably not a good idea to have the `SlugField` in a base class or a mixin, because you don't know which field to use to populate the `slug`. For one concrete model it could be `name` and for another `title`. You should probably use `self.str()` if you must make it abstract.

Comment: This would be more of an issue if there were more than one field they all shared, or if they were related taxonomically or in some other way than just having a slug field. I don't think avoiding this minor repetition with inheritance is a good idea.

Comment: @Lemayzeur, I have check other resources; adding def save(self, *args, **kwargs): self.slug = slugify(self.name) super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs) to each model I think would defeat the DRY-ness. I don't know how to get the name from models that inherited BaseModel, and have this code inside Base model.

Comment: @Josh21 Note that since you're using Python 3, `super()` doesn't take any arguments. Putting `name` on `BaseModel` would allow you to set the slug in `BaseModel.save()`, but obviously only works if all child classes need a `name`, which is why I suggest avoiding this unless there are other fields that are shared (even then, though, this is a questionable approach for maintanability and readability given the questionable benefits).

Comment: @Selcuk, I was thinking the same, as you pointed out, I don't know in advance which field to use to populate the slug, however, there should be some workaround for this. Also as you mentioned, how could I use the self.str()?

Comment: @kungphu, that was a code snippet I copied somewhere, thanks though. As also pointed by Selcuk, this may not be a good idea.

Comment: Josh21 to know how to get the fields from models, it's better to use a slug field for each model since as @Selcuk said the slug could be generated from the name or another title.

Comment: There are third party packages such as `django-autoslug` that handle this quite elegantly. You can use one of those packages or examine their source code as a reference.

Comment: @Selcuk, thanks for the info!